# Android Wear application not compatible, but when debugging it is?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I recently published an android wear application to the google play store, but when i go to the webpage it tells me the application is not compatible with my registered devices. But one of the devices is the android wear i am using to develop the same application on.

The play store isn't telling me what's wrong with the application and why it isn't compatible so i am a bit lost. Anybody can tell me if i am doing anything wrong (Below you will find the manifest and build.gradle)?

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bartimeus.hapticswear"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:wear:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.bartimeus.hapticswear">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".service.HapticsFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.AlarmActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_alarm" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is it a paid app? As in, not free to install?

Comment: @String, it is completely free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Play console

- go to your app
- on the left hand menu choose "Device catalogue"
- choose "All devices"
- choose the device you think should be compatible, by searching by manufacturer

If it is not compatible it should show you why.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Here was stated that the application was declined by google. Need to fix some issues and then the application should work in the playstore. I will test this and if that fixes it i will accept this as answer.